# magento customer table join query group by make problem in pagination

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, join-table

I wrote the join query with customer table. the query is, when I execute this query they will return 5 records:

```
$collection = $this->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('userid')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('profile_image')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('specialist')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', 5);
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('rating' => 'flrating'), 
        'e.entity_id = rating.reviewed_user_id', 
        array('total_rating' => 'count(rating.review_id)')
    );
$collection->getSelect()
    ->group('e.entity_id');
```

But when I execute the simple query they will return correct result (6 records):

```
$collection = $this->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('userid')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('profile_image')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('specialist')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', 5);
return $collection;
```

Even I put the following code in collection table also the code is:

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
    return $countSelect;
}
```

Can you please explain what is my problem and how to overcome the pagination issue, for your further information see the below screen:

**Result with join query:**
[image: Result with join query]

**Result with simple query:**

[image: Result with simple query]

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
$collection = $this ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('userid', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'profile_image', 'specialist'))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', array('eq' => 5));
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('rating'=>'flrating'),'main_table.entity_id = rating.reviewed_user_id',array('total_rating'=>'count(rating.review_id)'));
$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

Comment: throw an error : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.entity_id' in 'group statement'

Comment: Add the following line after first statement: 
`Mage::log((string)$collection->getSelect(),null,'test.log');`
And then go to /var/log/test.log and check what's the name used by main_table

Answer (score 1):

Look like your query is OK. I don't know the structure of table lawer (customer), but the last one should be:

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('e.userid');
```